# How do I reference a Class object in JRuby?

Tags: ruby, jruby

I need to pass the object class to a method (gson.fromJson)
but JRuby says: `'org.jruby.gen.InterfaceImpl624212141@187ef71' is not a Class`

How do I reference a Class (e.g. Bob.class) in JRuby?

---

```
include Java 
include_class Java::com.google.gson.Gson
include_class Java::com.bobmanager.Bob

def json_load(filename)
  gson = Gson.new
  jsonBob = IO.read filename
  $dto = gson.fromJson jsonBob, Bob.class  # <-- here is the problem: Bob.class  
end

json_load 'C:/json/1152.json'
```

---

Produces the following:

```
<stack_trace_array message='org.jruby.embed.EvalFailedException: Native Exception: 'class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException'; Message: Type 'org.jruby.gen.InterfaceImpl624212141@187ef71' is not a Class, ParameterizedType, or GenericArrayType. Can't extract class.; StackTrace: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type 'org.jruby.gen.InterfaceImpl624212141@187ef71' is not a Class, ParameterizedType, or GenericArrayType. Can't extract class.
    at com.google.gson.TypeUtils.toRawClass(TypeUtils.java:83)
    at com.google.gson.TypeInfo.<init>(TypeInfo.java:34)
    at com.google.gson.ObjectNavigator.accept(ObjectNavigator.java:102)
    at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContextDefault.fromJsonObject(JsonDeserializationContextDefault.java:73)
    at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContextDefault.deserialize(JsonDeserializationContextDefault.java:51)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:568)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:515)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:484)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:434)
' >
```

Comment: You might want to try Bob.java_class.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Bob.java_class` rather than `Bob.class`

Comment: I have noticed that if the Ruby class extends a java class then java_class actually returns the superclass. Has anyone else observed this? If so how do I get the reference to the java class?